# preserve the layout (and recreate it) of panels and editors in vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I use vs code on a two monitor setup and have usually 3 editors and a terminal open (now, after the change to version 1.64, unfortunately 4 editors, with one containing the terminal).

The layout must be such that the break between the two monitors agrees precisely with the break of two editor. I would like to store the layout, once established and be able to re-establish it after it was disturbed with other commands and after close and restart.

How to achieve this with vs code? Or is there a easier way to use two monitors with vs code?